# Pandas erroneously adding 0 before an int in a series of mixed datatype

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a csv with a sample shown below:
[image]

When I read this csv into pandas using the read_csv, Pandas inserts a 0 for the first row in the Branch Identifier 2 column as shown below:

[image]

This seems to be a problem only when the data is for integer types. For the next line in the csv, pandas reads it correctly as shown below:

[image]

How can I read the csv in pandas in such a way that the data is exactly the same as csv?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you passing a converter parameter when reading it in? It is important to show how you are reading in your data.

Comment: could you check for this in your code?

Comment: I'm reading the csv as shown:
busmap = pd.read_csv(fileloc,skiprows=2)